# Error when trying to move FXML files in e(fx)clipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx-8, efxclipse

I have this code and this file hierarchy:
[image]
Everything seems to be fine, hovewer I get this error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3201)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3169)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3142)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3118)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3098)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3091)
    at com.model.tomaszm.Main.start(Main.java:15)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1616271442.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/1051754451.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1139233777.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1775282465.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Suspicious is that when i try to move FXML file to different packages in eclipse I get this message dialog error:
*An internal error occurred during: "Search progress polling".
Invalid thread access*

Comment: Not sure about the Eclipse error, but I think you need `getResource("/com/root/tomaszm/MainRoot.fxml")`, with the structure you have. `com.root.tomaszm` is a package name, not a folder name.

Comment: Your right. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FXML throws that error when it cannot find the FXML document you wish to load.

Looking at the screenshot, this looks like it should get you past the error you're experiencing:

```
Parent root = 
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/root/tomaszm/MainRoot.fxml"));
```